# Python - Flatten a Tree which has N Children (N-ary tree)

Tags: python, tree, flatten

I want to flatten an N-ary tree into a list like so:

```
      P
______|______
|     |     |
C1    C2    C3         =>     [P,C1,C4,C2,C3,C5,C6]
|         ___|____
C4        |      |
         C5      C6
```

This is the node class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
```

Comment: isn't this simply depth-first traversal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node(object):
    ...
    def flatten(self):
        return [self.data] + sum(
            (c.flatten() for c in self.children),
            [],
        )
```

Not necessarily the easiest to understand, but I wanted to try and solve for the one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, which works.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
    def flatten(self):
        out = [self]
        for child in self.children:
            out += child.flatten()
        return out
```

I tried for a while to reach a one liner solution such as `return [self] + [child.flatten() for child in self.children]` but it never worked as it created nested lists. If anyone does know a neater way please share.

Comment: Search for "python flatten list".